# How to transfer from doing algorithm questions to making apps?

Tags: java, software-design

I recently learned java by reading the book Head First Java and I also bought the book Effective Java which I'm planning to finish later. I've been searching the ways to improve Java programming skills online but all I found are algorithm practice questions just like questions in the book Cracking the Coding Interview. I finished about a hundred of them and I found they are useful; however, I still cannot see how this is related to making real object oriented applications like desktop softwares or Android Apps. 
Every time I visit stackoverflow.com, under tag Java I see those questions about things that I have never heard of. I'm really frustrated. Am I on the wrong track to the real programming world?
Thanks.

Comment: Do stuff. Develop some applications, start with smaller ones and they'll rapidly get bigger. The problems you tackle will give you the knowledge you seek.

Comment: Find a simple project that you enjoy, maybe a game, and try to implement it, when done, improve it and make it more advanced. And read code, a lot of it, and try to understand how it works.

Comment: I would start by implementing simple things. Maybe a simple calculator just with +,-,/,*. You can extend it step by step. For example with cos, sin, a function plotter, ....

Comment: +1 to all comments above! Plus, by coming up with little projects for yourself, you never know, you might stumble on something you find extremely fascinating. Why don't you try and answer those "frustrating" SO questions about things you've never heard of? Personally, I learn the most by answering other peoples' questions.

Comment: If you come across a question on SO again which has tags about things you've never heard of, why not google those things and see if you can find out about them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options you might resort to, to improve your development and design skills. And all come through developing real-purpose applications. If you are at loss yourself to find a problem interesting enough and complex enough for you to exercise and hone your skills, you can always contribute to opensource projects. For instance you might go through java projects hosted in github, pick one you like, and have a look at its todo list if any, or pick a an issue and investigate it, fix it if you can and contribute a patch.

This exercise will expose you to product-grade codebases (depending on the project your chose) and several aspects of software development and will most certainly help you improve your skills.

[link](https://github.com/search?q=java&ref=cmdform) for java projects hosted at github

Comment: Thanks for the link, I just bookmarked it.